# Was mankind (adam) created in the image and likeness of God's heavenly assembly; where the Adam was made head over the rest of mankind as God's image?

Tags: creation, image-of-god

Does scripture teach in Gen. 1:26-28; that (a collective) man (H120, adam, i.e. mankind, the general word used for man, cp.  Ex 4:11); was made after the image and likeness of God's heavenly congregation (its function,  for ordered dominion); being ruled by the Highest Elohim (Ps. 89:5-7; 1 Kings 22:19-22; Ps. 82.1)?

The use of the definite article, "ha" Adam, "so God created "the" man in His own image"; is seemingly being used, by the author to distinguish between the creation of God's image (the Adam, singular meaning), and corporate mankind (adam, i.e., male and female). Who are identified as being created only in the likeness of elohim, *and given a name* (H8034, which word the translators excluded) male and female, see below, Gen.5.2)

Gen.1:26-27: "Elohim said let us (the Highest Elohim, addressing the divine council. Dan.4.17;1 Kings 22:20) make (or assign) man (i.e., mankind) in our image and likeness that they may rule..." (i.e. ordered hierarchy; for proper function against disorder, being typical of the heavenly family, Heb.8:5; Eph.3:15) that is under the wise order of the one Head (the Highest creator Elohim, i.e. The LORD God, Gen.3:22).

In which, the corporate mankind, like the elohim are given dominion over the different geographic locations (Dan.10:13, 20-21; Deut.32.8-9) with the Head (the Adam) reining from sacred space, as the image in sacrificial service ( the micro, i.e. Adam in Eden, with his faithful posterity, over the populations of the earth, teaching the ways of God, possibly horticulture, for life, and abundance (Gen.1:28-31;2:5,8,16); instead of hunting (Gen.10:8); where mankind was called to seek the Lord, and attend sacred space; in worship of God, in thanks giving during the appointed seasons (Gen.1:14;cp. Acts.17.26-27); the macrocosm finds fulfillment in the prophetic references below; where in the kingdom of God, Christ and His Church, will rein from the New Jerusalem; teaching the ways of the LORD to the nations, that are called to attend Jerusalem yearly during appointed seasons (Zech.8:20-23; 14:9,12-16; Isa.11.1-11; Ps.2 6-8; Rev. 2.26-28; 21:24-27).

Where “the” man was given the heirship (the first-born blessing) over the rest of mankind (possible inference to an existing corporate population when Adam was placed in the Garden see: Gen.2:11-15; Isa.14:4-8; cp. Ez.28:13). Being typical of Israel, and the Church (Ex.4:11; Heb.12:23); in corporate vocation, and allotment in God's Kingdom, as priest-king heirs over the rest of the nations (Isa.60:11-12; 61:6; Rev.1:6; 2:26-27).

To which, Christ Jesus, is the anti-type, the Son of Man (i.e. Son of Adam, Dan.7.13-14, cp. Lk.3.23,38); being the true heir of the inheritance that was allotted to "the" Adam (i.e. the image, Ps.8; 1Cor. 15: 24-28); who is the expressed image of God, the Son of God, the firstborn of all creation, who has been placed above all creation (Heb. 1:2-3; Col.1.15-18; Eph.1.20-21).

So, in v 27: "God created “the” man in His image (as the son of God, Lk.3:38); in the image God, He created him (the Adam); male and female He (God) created them ..."(implying a separate act of creation in corporal form, as God did with the rest of the created creatures, Gen. 1:23-25).

Gen. 5:2: This is the book of the genealogy of man (kind) in the day God created man (kind) in the likeness of Elohim, He made him (mankind), and called him a name (H8034) male, and female… this is looking back to Cains genealogy in  chapter four (as 2:4 does to chapter 1); who lost the inheritance and is identified with the cooperate creation (man).

5:3 and lived Adam 130 years and he begat a son in his own likeness and image... Seth. Here Adam is used without the art. as well in 4:25-26; which are parenthetical; where "Adam" as just (man),is used by the author, to clearly identifying "the" Adam of previous chapters, being that he begat Seth. The lack of the art, is for the reader to trace the theme of inheritance, and God's image-heir; identifying the transfer of the inheritance of God (motif,cp. Gen.25.) unto Seth; and is the apparent reason,  for the force of language  Seth was in the "image" and "likeness" of His father (given the first born blessing cp. Mt.5.44-48); with further implication of this, when "men began to call on the name of the Lord"; weather this insertion be interpreted as the fufilling of the vocation of spreading of the word, or idolatry, both support the view given; of vocation, linked with inheritance, within the seed conflict motif (Gen.3.15).

Gen.9:6 use, of image and "the" adam, sets the laws of the land according to God's law as His imagers, who are to set forth the character of God as His heirs (cp. Mt.5:44-48).

So while "the" Adam is a part of mankind being in the likeness of elohim, seen in the shared dominion given to humanity over the animals (Ps.8); He exclusively held the title of image, with access and fellowship with God in sacred space (Gen.3.8), and given a vocation which involves king priest duties, seen in the grammatical links used for Adam in the garden, and the priest hood of the Levitical law ( see Adam as the First Priest in
Eden as the Garden Temple1
G. K. Beale).

Also, looking at a New Testament reference concerning image, it says only the man is the image of God, leaving the woman out, this seems to go along with the above view of the creation account 1 Cor.11:7; is this what the text is teaching, it seems to fit, and be a clear teaching that has been overlooked?

Comment: "pantheon" is never mentioned in the Bible.  I am not sure what you are asking.  Mankind (both male and female) was made in the image of God.

Comment: Touched it up for you hope it helps

Comment: Please change "counsel" (which means "advice") to "council",

Comment: You should remove non-Biblical concepts of a "divine council" - only God made man in His image, according to the Bible. Angels do not create, nor is there any "divine council" in Scripture.

Comment: Have you read what I wrote or looked at my references because no one said angels create. Also  divine counsel is in the Bibles Ps 82 .1, Take a little more time to look, before jumping to conclusions . Also Dan 4.11 the decree of the watchers what's that?

Comment: The Bible NEVER mentions any body with the title: "council of elohim" (of their corporate order, and function).  This question is badly framed.

Comment: Thanks, made some adjustments, that's the best I got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Rabbinic Treatment**
The Rabbis recognized the problem of a text which states, "*Let **us** make man in **our** image and after **our** likeness...*" The use of first person plural pronouns means *Elohim* is plural. The "work around" explanation invokes a "divine council" (by whatever term it is called) [emphasis added]:

> The Gemara asks: Why do I need these instances of plural words? Why does the verse employ the plural at all when referring to God? The Gemara explains: This is in accordance with the statement of Rabbi Yoḥanan, as Rabbi Yoḥanan says: **The Holy One, Blessed be He, does not act unless He consults with the entourage of Above**, i.e., the angels, as it is stated: “The matter is by the decree of the watchers, and the sentence by the word of the holy ones” (Daniel 4:14). <sup>**1**</sup>

The Rabbis understood the plural as *Elohim* speaking or consulting with angels.

This claim, if true creates serious difficulties:

- There is no mention of angels in Genesis 1 and 2.
- The divine council is not found until much later (i.e. Daniel 4:14). This means the inital readers would be misled or at least unable to understand the passage until a thousand years after it was written.
- If the Rabbis are correct that *Elohim* **never** acts without consulting others, then the others, like *Elohim* must be eternal, uncreated beings.

The last point proves the divine council explanation is impossible, and proves *Elohim*, as the dictionary states, is plural. Before the beings who would make up the divine council were created *Elohim* did not act without consulting the "others" whom are only *Elohim*: a clear picture of what can be called the Trinity.

**Genesis 1 and Genesis 2**
After announcing the plans to **make** man using first person plural pronouns three times, the next verse states what *Elohim* did:

> So *Elohim* **created** [the] man, in his own image, image of *Elohim* he **created** him, male and female he **created** them.

The plural verb from verse 26, *asa* becomes the singular *bara* which is repeated three times. Since the divine council explanation for the first person plural pronouns is deficient and essentially proves *Elohim* should be understood as plural, what follows should be considered in that light. *Elohim* declares man is to be **made** in our image and after our likeness.

The making, *asa*, of man, **not** "the" man, in our image, **begins** by creating, *bara*, "the" man in his own image, in the image of *Elohim* he created him, male and female he created them. Genesis 2 details "the" man was created before the woman by being formed out of the dust.<sup>**2**</sup> When the LORD God breathed into his nostrils, the man became a living being. The woman was made, *bana* from the man later.

The details in Genesis 2 follow the three part seqeunce of Genesis 1:27.

1. "The" man was formed from the earth. (Let us make man/"the" man was created)
2. The breath from the LORD God made him a living being (in our image/in the image of *Elohim* he created him).
3. The woman was made (after our likeness/male and female he created them).

**Conclusion**
The use of the article in Genesis 1:27, "the" man means Adam was made before the woman. The plural image and likeness of Elohim is physically present in the creating of male and female. "The" man is tripartite: water, dust, spirit. "Man" is tripartite: male, spirit, female.

---

<sub>1. Babylonian Talmud, [Sanhedrin 38b, 16](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.38b.14?lang=bi).</sub>
<sub>2. *But a spring rose out of the earth, watering all the surface of the earth.* (Genesis 2:6) Essentially, the man was made from the dust of the earth which was watered, that is, clay.</sub>

Comment: Good point i was coming to that conclusion as well, but need to think more on it

Comment: The only problem i see with your conclusion is the singular use of likeness, and not image; used for mankind (H120, without the art., in Gen. 5:3). So i guess my view is claiming a separate corporate creation, besides Adam, and eve. "male and female He created them" along with the other details i put forth, but maybe i am wrong I still have to think on it.

Comment: @ThatwemaybethepraiseofHisglory Your comment is about Genesis 5:3? "And Adam lived an hundred and thirty years, and begat a son in his own likeness, after his image; and called his name Seth" Also H119 to H124 are all spelled אדם. They have different Strong's number because Strong numbered them according to the Masoretic text. The original Hebrew lacked the vowel markings. One reading אדם would either have to have had a particular verse passed on, or to decide from context which pronounciation was appropriate.

Comment: @ThatwemaybethepraiseofHisglory Genesis 5:1-2 speaks of creating אדם in the likeness of God. Male and female He created (*bara*) them. This follows what was said in Genesis 1:26 and left unsaid in Genesis 1:27. אדם is referring to both. This is affirmed by 5:2 where God calls **their** name אדם in the day they were created (*bara*). Genesis 5:3 speaks of procreation after the day of creation. When we read אדם had a son 130 years later, remember both male and female were the same age and had the same name and were involved in having a son. The lack of the article with אדם refers to  both.

Comment: So you take the the  the genealogy to be referring to what follows,  then what is past? Because that phrase,   clearly seems to be looking back to chapter 1. Cp. 2.4; but the subject we are talking about now, was a difficulty,  so scholars force the meaning to be what follows.

Comment: @ThatwemaybethepraiseofHisglory Genesis 5:1-2 restate the creation of the first two. In that sense it is looking back. The term used is אדם, without the article. Therefore it is not speaking about “the” man; it is referring to “man” as both of them. In Genesis 1:27 the man is created in the image of God. Genesis 2 has details of how that happened and describe the man who was formed before the woman and how the woman was made from man. Genesis 5:1-2 state אדם (no article) was created in the likeness of God. This completes what was stated in 1:26, image and likeness, but left unsaid until 5:1-2.

Comment: Genesis 5:3 describes the birth of a child, 130 years after אדם (no article) was created in the likeness of God. This event also involved both male and female, not “the” man. It is easy to overlook אדם is referring to both in 5:3. But obviously the man cannot have a son without the woman who is the same age. If one wanted to placed an emphasis on just one of the two as having a son, it should be the woman who has the bigger part in having a child. Also Seth is described as in the likeness and image of אדם.

Comment: Yes but 5.3 identifies adam h120, with the man Adam, by context, adam, in 5.2, looks back to the genealogy just mentioned, as in 2.4; that's a problem with your view, if you honestly look at that

Comment: I think your view is good, but it doesn'tfully answer the key points I pointed out. I  can't except an answer within myself, if it doesn't settle the issues brought up.

Comment: @ThatwemaybethepraiseofHisglory A key premise in your question is the heavenly congregation. I show that is not possible.

Comment: 2 kings mentions the host, so does job in reference to the sons of God. So I don't think it creates difficulties.

Comment: So when it says he created them, is a recreation of Adam, or is it when humanity was created? Which would still be considered a double creation, only problem with  that is the seed conflict,  but God created the elohim, so maybe a guess from Adam God man humanity in eve, the mother of the living. But I don't know still seems like he created other people at once, Like the animals I feel like the weight is leaning more on that side given everything.

Comment: God* created humanity.. ether way I think it establishes the doctrine of the image-heir, separate from the rest. That's what I get from it. So thanks for your time and attention.

Comment: Also you have to understand that when the Hebrews received these text, they where well aware of counsels of God's, it was surrounded in there culture, and, the host ruleing the day and night is in reference to beings the have been given dominion in Gen.1.15-18; according to the ANE

Comment: **There is no mention of angels in any creation account.**, This is not exactly true. Angels are referred to as sons of God in Job 38:4-7 and are present at the founding of the world.

Comment: @Austin The creation account in Genesis. The point is such an idea requires importing information from other books. I’m not saying the belief angels had been created before man is wrong, I’m saying that is not found in Genesis. Plus if the divine council is appropriate to understanding the use of the plural pronouns as Rabbi Yohannan claims, then who did God consult with before creating angels? Either way it is God who is plural.

Comment: @RevelationLad **The creation account in Genesis.** You said *any creation account.* This looks like moving the goal post. Since when is it a bad hermeneutical principle to make use of relevant clarifying scripture to help inform you of a passage in question? **who did God consult with before creating angels?** This is irrelevant as the passage in question doesn't address creation of angels or what happened prior to the 6 day creation and thus cannot be used to assert that plural pronouns were necessary in prior creation events.

Comment: @Austin 1) I have edited the answer to reflect Genesis. 2) You may use whatever hermeneutical principle you feel is appropriate. IMO expecting a reader of Genesis to import hypothetical explanations from Job or Psalms or any other book in order to understand Genesis is farfetched. 3) My point of consulting when making angels is a rebuttal to the Rabbi Yohannan who claims God **never** acts without consulting with the entourage of above. I simply apply the Rabbi's logic - if what he says is true who did God consult with before acting to create angels? Either the Rabbi is wrong or God is plural.

Comment: @RevelationLad, 1) very well 2) It's not about expecting the reader of Genesis to import hypothetical explanations from Job or Psalms, but using Job or Psalms to inform the thoughtful 21st century reader of the comprehensive world view that may plausibly been in the mind of the author of Genesis. The Trinitarian world view is less well attested in the Old Testament as a viewpoint than the divine counsel view.  3) Perhaps, the Rabbi was speaking only of the concrete events recorded in the Bible like how you were only talking about Genesis accounts and not all creation narratives.

Comment: @RevelationLad, I do appreciate your desire to modify your text regarding creation to match your intention. If you had attempted to do so already, it didn't take. And one last critique: **The divine council is not found until much later (i.e. Daniel 4:14).** The divine council is present in Psalm 82,  (much earlier than Daniel), 1 Kings, 2 Chronicles, and Job (even older). Trinitarian Michael Heiser traces it back to Deuteronomy in the DSS & LXX. So, if you have all these ancient textual references throughout the OT it is not unreasonable that this view would also inform Genesis.

Comment: @Austin There are two issues you ignore. 1) If God never acts without consulting the divine council, who did He consult with before creating those who later are in the divine council? 2) If God never acts without consulting the divine council, why is there no mention of this council until the last things which God created? The divine council theory, which is not found in Genesis means God tricked the reader into thinking the Elohim which is a plural word really was “us” until they read some other book, which merely presents the council without ever stating it was the “us” in Genesis.

Comment: @RevelationLad, 1) I didn't ignore this, I addressed this. *Perhaps, the Rabbi was speaking only of the concrete events recorded in the Bible like how you were only talking about Genesis accounts and not all creation narratives* thus the angel do not need to be uncreated. Also, If Rabbi is correct God created the angels specifically so that they would be involved in decisions for the rest of creation. 2) The tricking only happens because you are reading Genesis 4000 years after it was written. Your ignorance of their worldview & assumptions would be what is tricking you & not the text itself.

Comment: @RevelationLad, P.S. you still haven't made the changes you said you made.

Answer (score 1):

The OP asks: "does scripture teach...?"  Given the variety of doctrines that come from the scripture in question, the answer is in the eye of the beholder. There are at least four ways of interpreting the phrase "let *us* make man in our image" in Gen 1:26:

- God was using the "royal we," not addressing anyone else.
- God the Father spoke to the other persons that comprise the Trinity.
- God spoke to the angels.
- God spoke to the council of the *elohim*.

The  OP asks particularly about the fourth of these choices. This is plausible if one holds to the idea that the beings later called "angels" were originally thought of as lesser gods. According to this hypothesis, the god El was the father of the gods, together with his consort Asherah. He was also the head of council of the gods. [Kaspars Ozolins](https://www.desiringgod.org/articles/the-divine-council) of the Southern Baptist Theological Seminary writes:

> A famous series of large tablets, called the “Baal cycle,” contains
> epic texts that depict a divine council of deities, headed by the
> chief god ’Ilu (a word that is related to the generic words for God in
> biblical Hebrew: ’Ēl and ’Ĕlōhîm). Featuring prominently in the epic
> is the deity Ba‘lu, parallel to the Hebrew word Ba‘al...  In the epic, Ba‘lu engages in annual combat with Môtu, the god of
> death and drought... Although Ba‘lu is defeated and descends into the underworld, he is
> subsequently assisted by ‘Anatu and Šapšu...
>
> Other deities could be named as part of the divine council of gods:
> ’Aṯiratu (related to Hebrew ’Ăšērâ, “Asherah”) was seen as the wife
> of ’Ilu and his consort. Kôṯaru-wa-Ḫasīsu was the craftsman of the
> council, who helped fashion a mace for Ba‘lu. Yammu (related to Hebrew
> yām, “sea”) was the god of the seas and another adversary of Ba‘lu.

As the OP mentions, several scriptures refer to the council of the "elohim" or "bene-elohim,"  variously translated. For purposes of this question, Psalm 82:1 is particularly relevant:

> God has taken his place in the divine council; in the midst of the
> gods he holds judgment. (RSV)

The psalmist goes on to describe the demotion of these "elohim" because of their corruption. Although interpretations vary, one that fits with the OP's question is the idea that this psalm represents the period in which the Israelite religion was shifting from henotheism (belief in many gods of which only  one deity was worshiped) to monotheism (belief in the existence of only one God).

I will skip other questions raised by the OP's analysis. Grammatical issues in the Hebrew are beyond my expertise, and treating other issues will make the answer too long.

**Conclusion**. The scripture does not definitely teach that humanity was created in the image of [the council of] the gods, but that is one of several possible interpretations of the text of Gen. 1:26. However this does challenge a strictly monotheistic viewpoint.

Comment: I don't think I am saying adam.was created in the image of a counsel,  but humanity, with Adam as head, being the image of God. If that adds clarity.

Comment: thanks... I'll change my answer accordingly. The basic answer does not change.

Comment: Can you give your argument for why textualy? Because what I layed out seems to be a more accurate understanding than tradition has held with the theological developments in understanding the role of the image, concerning vocation?

Comment: Because your conclusion rested on the variety of historical interpretation, in which you chose one of them. I am looking for more of a textual, expositional proof

Answer (score 0):

**Male Adam** (but not female Eve!) **was made in the image** (visual appearance) **of the Father YHWH El who is Himself of male gender and sits on the throne in the heavens among the Divine Council elohim angels, his not-begotten sons.**

YHWH created the Divine Council and Adam through Jesus His only-begotten Son who is himself the head of that Divine Council. As YHWH said to the pre-incarnate Jesus, "Come, let us make Adam in our image." (Gen.1:26) And it was said in the genealogy, "Adam, the Son of Elohim." (Luk.3:38)

Father YHWH has a spirit body which is in appearance similar to the that of the human race, however YHWH has an immortal heavenly body, whereas humanity has mortal earthly bodies. He sits on a throne and has a face and limbs, nevertheless dwelling in approachable light as He is the Spirit from whom all spirits come, the "Father of heavenly lights" (Jas.1:17)

Jesus is the personal Son of Father YHWH and was created by the Father YHWH (Col.1:15) in His image, and therefore also in the likeness like Adam, YHWH be praised above all. However, Father YHWH made Adam through Jesus the Son, who was the master workman *through* whom all things come but not *from* whom come the things, which come from our Father YHWH the one true Eloah.

And all of the usual elohim (heavenly angels/sons of El) also share that visual likeness with YHWH and man, namely a body that is indistinguishable from man in appearance. This does not include the higher classes of angels, such as the Seraphim chimeras or the Ophanim wheels with eyes.

Comment: you bring out some interesting points, as far as appearance which i think isa big part of the subject, which needs integration in my understanding of the subject of image; I see the image as primarily referring to vocation and role; as God's proxy that He rules through " in order that they may have dominion..."

Comment: @ThatwemaybethepraiseofHisglory Certainly role as proxy, but it is more specifically the literal appearance being the stamp of symbol and dominion of being formed in God's very own image and likeness, visually.

Comment: What's your view of the diety of Christ, because in your explanation, I am curious?

Comment: Do you believe He is YHWH

Comment: @ThatwemaybethepraiseofHisglory I do not believe that Christ is YHWH God, but that he is the only-begotten Son of YHWH God. He is the one Lord and sole exalted intercessor between YHWH God and humanity. I believe that Christ is the sublime Light of the world and the express image and perfect imprint in nature of YHWH God his Father.

Comment: @ThatwemaybethepraiseofHisglory Furthermore, I believe that Christ was pre-incarnate and is now post-incarnate as the Angel of YHWH who stood as God on behalf of God his Father to lead God's people from beginning to end. Nobody can see the Father God and live, but we can see the Father God through his Son on behalf of God and live.

Comment: @Joshua B. I completely agree with what you said above regarding Jesus Christ being the Angel of the Lord. However, I completely disagree with you that Jesus Christ is "NOT" YHWH" God. I base this from Genesis 22. TAOTL at vs11 & 15 calls to Abraham from heaven. Vs16, and said, "By Myself I have sworn declares the Lord because you have done this thing." Vs17, "indeed I will greatly bless you and multiply your seed etc. Vs18, "And in your seed all the nations of the earth will be blessed because you have OBEYED MY VOICE." Now look at Hebrews 6:13, "For when God made the promise to Abraham, cont

Comment: since He could swear by no one greater, He swore BY HIMSELF, vs14, saying, I will surely bless you, and I will surely multiply you." I shortened this but the point is that the angel of the Lord has to be God because only God can swear an oath on behalf of Himself. This is what Hebrews 6:13 is saying. Also, the Hebrew word for angel is "malak" and it simply means messenger. Jesus is not an actual angel but the messenger of His Father as you stated. Read John 14:9-17. Also read Malachi 1:3. The AOTL first appears as the AOTL at Genesis 16:9. Note vs13, and who appeared at Genesis 17:1-3

Comment: TAOTL swore by himself because He is the Son of God who was given the personal name of God, the Tetragrammaton YHWH. By wielding the YHWH name, the Angel of YHWH was able to wear by himself on behalf of YHWH God his Father.

Comment: I think the problem is the doctrine of the preexisting sonship of christ, before he was flesh he was the word, once he was born as a man he became the son of God.

Comment: That's how John 1 lays it out, and col 1, is talking about his exaltation as first-born after his resurrection.

Comment: His reward, but we see he is the creator God as well.

Answer (score 0):

1 Corinthians 15:45

> And so it is written, The first man Adam was made a living soul; the last Adam was made a quickening spirit.

1 Corinthians 15:49

> And as we have borne the image of the earthy, we shall also bear the image of the heavenly.

Hebrews 1:3

> Who being the brightness of his glory, and the express image of his person, and upholding all things by the word of his power, when he had purged our sins, sat down on the right hand of the Majesty on high.

Revelation 1:6

> And hath made us Kings and priests unto God and his Father; to him be glory and dominion for ever and ever. Amen.

Revelation 5:10

> And hast made us unto our God Kings and priests: an we shall reign on the earth.

Revelation 21:5

> And he that sat upon the throne said, Behold I make all things new.

Conclusion: It took Jesus' coming and dying as a man (Adam) to be the perfect sacrifice for the original sin committed in the Garden of Eden. When the gospel was preached to Gentiles and the whole world, the chosen status became irrelevant. There is neither Jew or Greek, male or female: for ye are all one in Christ Jesus.

Comment: The church is chosen, once that company is completed, they will have an inheritance greater than the nations, for the kings of nationst bring their offerings to the new Jerusalem.  So we can't just scramble all the different groups found in the bible, because of one verse, there is  no differences in the church, but the church will be different then the nations.

Comment: @ThatwemaybethepraiseofHisglory Agreed. Did you you read the verses I posted in response to your question

Comment: Yes, I am trying to understand your point sorry, in how it fits

Comment: @ThatwemaybethepraiseofHisglory The verses quoted in revelation involving Christians serving as Kings and priest with Jesus should have answered your request for new testament documentation. What started in Genesis 1&2 is fulfilled through Jesus and those that become children of God. We can take one question at a time if you wish.

Comment: I am confused,  I have no idea what we are talking about.